# iOS Search Controller - show search bar at the start

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I want to show the Search engine when viewLoad the controller.
I do not mean:

```
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

I want to hide the search engine while scrolling.
I only want to show it once at the start,
How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: I do not have a solution yet